# Use a script to effect on all of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that retrieve some images from database and display them. Now I want to add some effects to them. I have use a jquery plugin. look at my code please :

[image]

But the script effect just on the first occurred image not all of them. Where is the problem?

Comment: If you have a JavaScript problem, then please show us the client side code. Don't show us a picture of the server side code that generates the client side code.

Comment: where is the jquery code

Comment: @krshekhar — In the bottom half of the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using an id as a selector (`$('#kio')`, the # means it's an id) and id's are unique to the page, so only one will be returned. So you should leave the id attribute out of the img tag.

The solution is to use a selector that gives you all the elements you want, in this case probably `$('.adipoli-wrapper img')` the first part selects all elements with class `adipoli-wrapper`, then the img part will select all `img` elements found within those elements.

On a side note: the classname `adipoli-wrapper>img` you have in your code is not a valid classname,, you probably mean just `adipoli-wrapper`, that what I'm assuming in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the JQuery selectors to get all the images in the page:

```
$('img').adipoli({
        'startEffect': 'overlay',
        'hoverEffect': 'sliceDown'
```

});

Answer (score 0):

ID must be unique for each element, use class instead or tag name with context:

```
$('.myImgClass').adipoli({
            'startEffect': 'overlay',
            'hoverEffect': 'sliceDown'
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

ID must be unique first of all that's why it's only taking effect on first element with that id so instead of that try this

```
$('.adipoli-wrapper img').adipoli({
            'startEffect': 'overlay',
            'hoverEffect': 'sliceDown'
});
```

it will take effect on all image tag in span that has class adipoli-wrapper or give your image tag a unique class and use this

```
 $('.YourClassName').adipoli({
                'startEffect': 'overlay',
                'hoverEffect': 'sliceDown'
 });
```